# How do I create displacement on a hemishere which can be 3D printed

Tags: modeling, objects, image, 3d-printing, displacement

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4v-GkVPDQUQNlJYZTltcmFrMUU/view?usp=sharing

I am trying to create a printable height map from a hemisphere shape.

The way I know how to do it on a flat plane is to use the displacement modifier and use an image. When I use an image that have the dimensions of the Radius (for Height) and Circumference (for Width) it creates the result shown in the above link.

I would like to know how to do it so that the image can wrap around the hemisphere and show the relief of the image. I would also like to do it in a way that would have minimal distortion of the image when I'm done. The image of the flower will not be the image I use for the final product, I just used this as a test. The final image will be a full image.

Later I would cut the object into pieces for easier 3D printing but right now I just want to get the object created.

Comment: although different shape, this could help you http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63106/how-to-decorate-cyclinder

Comment: The trick here is unwraping your mesh in such way that the image fits nicely on top with little distortions. The rest should be the same as a flat mesh. See [how to unwrap a sphere in Blender](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=vid&q=blender%20unwrap%20sphere)